# access the content of EditText when back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-edittext, back-button

I'm working with fragments. Suppose I have fragmentA and fragmentB and I can go from fragmentA  to fragmentB. In fragmentA I have a form (several edit texts). If I fill the form and then go to fragmentB and then press back button, all the information that I typed in the form is retained. From onCreateView I'm trying to do

```
String name = myEditText.getText().toString();
```

But I get empty result, even when I'm seeing the values in the form.

The question is, how can I access the content of this EditText in this situation?.

**Solution**

```
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String id = etIdHidden.getText().toString();

    if(id.equals("")==false){

                    //Here do whatever you need, in my case I needed to change a bundle
        mArgumentos=new Bundle();
            mArgumentos.putString("id", ""+id);

    }

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try fetching the value from the `editText` in the `onResume()` method. Also refer to the life-cycle of the fragment in the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html